# I am working with NFL positional data provided for the 2022 NFL Big Data bowl and I can't get the package GGanimate to animate the play in R

Tags: r, animation, gganimate

I was working on data provided by the NFL for the "Big Data Bowl" and I could not get the points to move as the code intended. Instead, I am getting screenshots of each frame of the data, rather than it flowing together in the animation. Can anyone help identify problems in my code?

The data can be accessed [here](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/nfl-big-data-bowl-2022/data) on the NFL Big Data Bowl 2022 page on Kaggle.

```
# Big Data Bowl

##### Understanding How to Plot Players Moving 


library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
library(cowplot)



#Load a week to view a play 
week1<-read.csv("week1.csv")
head(week1)

#Load the Plays Data
plays<-read.csv("plays.csv")
head(plays)

#Load the Player Data
player<-read.csv("players.csv")
head(player)

#----------------------- Make an example Play ---------------------------------------

# Join the three data sets together
tracking.example.merged <- week1 %>% inner_join(plays) %>% inner_join(player) 
tracking.example.merged[tracking.example.merged$playResult==-8,] # Play 4298 Results in a -8 Yard Loss (Sack on Matt Ryan), we will use this as an example 

#Filter to Specific Play 
example.play <- tracking.example.merged %>% filter(playId == 4298)

example.play %>% select(playDescription) %>% slice(1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   playDescription
#1 (3:50) (No Huddle, Shotgun) M.Ryan sacked at ATL 41 for -8 yards (H.Ridgeway).

#-----------------------Set the Field-----------------------------------------
## General field boundaries
xmin <- 0
xmax <- 160/3
hash.right <- 38.35
hash.left <- 12
hash.width <- 3.3

## Specific boundaries for a given play
ymin <- max(round(min(example.play$x, na.rm = TRUE) - 10, -1), 0)
ymax <- min(round(max(example.play$x, na.rm = TRUE) + 10, -1), 120)
df.hash <- expand.grid(x = c(0, 23.36667, 29.96667, xmax), y = (10:110))
df.hash <- df.hash %>% filter(!(floor(y %% 5) == 0))
df.hash <- df.hash %>% filter(y < ymax, y > ymin)

animate.play <- ggplot() +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(6, 4, 6), guide = FALSE) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 16, 21), guide = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#e31837", "#654321", "#002244"), guide = FALSE) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "#654321", "#c60c30"), guide = FALSE) + 
  annotate("text", x = df.hash$x[df.hash$x < 55/2], 
           y = df.hash$y[df.hash$x < 55/2], label = "_", hjust = 0, vjust = -0.2) + 
  annotate("text", x = df.hash$x[df.hash$x > 55/2], 
           y = df.hash$y[df.hash$x > 55/2], label = "_", hjust = 1, vjust = -0.2) + 
  annotate("segment", x = xmin, 
           y = seq(max(10, ymin), min(ymax, 110), by = 5), 
           xend =  xmax, 
           yend = seq(max(10, ymin), min(ymax, 110), by = 5)) + 
  annotate("text", x = rep(hash.left, 11), y = seq(10, 110, by = 10), 
           label = c("G   ", seq(10, 50, by = 10), rev(seq(10, 40, by = 10)), "   G"), 
           angle = 270, size = 4) + 
  annotate("text", x = rep((xmax - hash.left), 11), y = seq(10, 110, by = 10), 
           label = c("   G", seq(10, 50, by = 10), rev(seq(10, 40, by = 10)), "G   "), 
           angle = 90, size = 4) + 
  annotate("segment", x = c(xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax), 
           y = c(ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin), 
           xend = c(xmin, xmax, xmax, xmin), 
           yend = c(ymax, ymax, ymin, ymin), colour = "black") + 
  geom_point(data = example.play, aes(x = (xmax-y), y = x, shape = team,
                                      fill = team, group = nflId, size = team, colour = team), alpha = 0.7) + 
  geom_text(data = example.play, aes(x = (xmax-y), y = x, label = jerseyNumber), colour = "white", 
            vjust = 0.36, size = 3.5) + 
  ylim(ymin, ymax) + 
  coord_fixed() +  
  theme_nothing() + 
  transition_time(frame.id)  +
  ease_aes('linear') + 
  NULL

## Ensure timing of play matches 10 frames-per-second
play.length.ex <- length(unique(example.play$frame.id))
animate(animate.play, fps = 10, nframe = play.length.ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

try installing  `gifski`  and `png` packages.
after installing restart RStudio and it should work.

Please refer to these extremally useful links:

- GitHub issues:
  https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/93
- More...
  https://gganimate.com/index.html#old-api
- Vingete:
  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gganimate/vignettes/gganimate.html
- Author:
  https://community.rstudio.com/u/mattwarkentin